# VPS inusable, out of memory errors

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, memory

I have a VPS with 512Mb RAM, 20Gb space and 100Mbps bandwidth.
I'm rather new at configuring servers.. I'm using this VPS to host some websites of mine. It's running Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Every TOT hours my server becomes inusable and I need to restart it in order to take control again. I saw these errors when I restarted it:

[image]

I have apache2, php5, mysql, phpmyadmin, exim4 installed.. Could it be a RAM problem? RAM went out of memory? If I had more RAM would I solve the problem?

Here are some graphs I can see from the panel:

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not the CPU is stressed has **nothing** to do with whether or not you're experiencing a RAM problem (which you are).

While purchasing more RAM will likely be a temporary solution to the problem, the real solution requires a bit more work.

In short, you need to re-configure apache and MySQL. Most distros ship apache and MySQL in configurations that assume you'll be running them on systems with lots of RAM. They will need to be tweaked to take into consideration the small amount of RAM available to them on your VPS.

In apache, look at your MPM settings, and make sure that you have an upper bound set on the number of apache processes that will start up. For MySQL, disable any functionality you don't need (InnoDB, for instance), and adjust cache/buffer settings.

There are multiple articles here on SF on the subject if you need more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :)
Can you be more specific on where do I modify MPM settings and how..?

Comment: [This](http://library.linode.com/troubleshooting/memory-networking#sph_apache-2-low-memory-settings) will give you a good start. It goes without saying, though, that any configuration you find only will need to be modified for your specific needs.